# Getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException via JMeter Plugins manager but JMeter tool is able to run the test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Using JMeter v5.4.3 and [Jmeter plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/) CMD (v1.7):

We're getting the following error while running jmeter plugins manager on a JMX and the required plugins are **not** getting installed, but surprisingly the same JMX is running fine on JMeter. Anything we're missing here?

```
{"asctime": "2022-03-24 07:32:29,478", "name": "execOp", "levelname": "INFO", "correlationId": "1e519b37-d640-48bb-b2c8-c8dea8bbb010", "servicename": "JMeter Job Agent", "classname": "execOp", "testRunId": "b4969e62-5a1c-446f-8602-d584dd54cd25", "testRunName": "1e519b37-d640-48bb-b2c8-c8dea8bbb00e", "message": "['PluginsManagerCMD.sh', 'install-for-jmx', '/root/artifacts/testplan.jmx']"}
2022-03-24 07:32:30,367 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Command is: install-for-jmx
2022-03-24 07:32:30,418 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Requesting https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/?installID=linux-a07ec75f950934652462a757ae53bcb4-nongui
2022-03-24 07:32:31,424 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-plugins-manager=1.7, jmeter-core=5.4.3, jmeter-ftp=5.4.3, jmeter-http=5.4.3, jmeter-jdbc=5.4.3, jmeter-jms=5.4.3, jmeter-junit=5.4.3, jmeter-java=5.4.3, jmeter-ldap=5.4.3, jmeter-mail=5.4.3, jmeter-mongodb=5.4.3, jmeter-native=5.4.3, jmeter-tcp=5.4.3, jmeter-components=5.4.3]
2022-03-24 07:32:31,426 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Params line is: /root/artifacts/testplan.jmx
2022-03-24 07:32:31,499 WARN o.j.r.p.TestPlanAnalyzer: Cannot parse file: /root/artifacts/testplan.jmx
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#x0" is an invalid XML character.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar:?]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer.getNodeListWithClassNames(TestPlanAnalyzer.java:112) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer.analyze(TestPlanAnalyzer.java:37) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.PluginSuggester.analyzeTestPlan(PluginSuggester.java:51) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.installPluginsForJmx(PluginManagerCMD.java:127) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:81) [jmeter-plugins-manager-1.7.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62) [cmdrunner-2.2.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21) [cmdrunner-2.2.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115) [cmdrunner-2.2.jar:?]
2022-03-24 07:32:31,516 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Downloading: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
2022-03-24 07:32:31,517 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Downloading json-lib...
2022-03-24 07:32:31,793 INFO o.j.r.PluginManagerCMD: Downloaded json-lib...
2022-03-24 07:32:31,795 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins manager will apply some modifications
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why "surprisingly"? Your .jmx script file contains a [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) which is not allowed character in XML.

JMeter ignores this in order to allow maximum flexibility and JMeter Plugins Manager doesn't.

Plugins Manager is a [separate project](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-manager) which is not related to JMeter upstream by any means.

Moreover it's a message of `WARN` severity so you can just ignore it (or if it causes problems in automated log analysis you can [configure JMeter logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) to not display this warning by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file)

```
<Logger name="org.jmeterplugins.repository.plugins.TestPlanAnalyzer" level="error" />
```

Comment: The problem is the plugin is not getting installed, even if it's a WARN message. So in the end such test plan throws an error with JMeter if it contains a plugin. But thanks for explaining that in general JMeter ignores such chars, that's why we're able to run such JMX without plugins.